# Replace the configuration file with regex

Tags: regex, sed

I am having the file `unbound.conf`

as below

```
## Simple recursive caching DNS, UDP port 53
## unbound.conf -- https://calomel.org
#
server:
   access-control: 10.0.0.0/8 allow
   verbosity: 1

forward-zone:
      name: "."
      forward-addr: 8.8.4.4        # Google
      forward-addr: 8.8.8.8        # Google

forward-zone:
      name: "example.com"
      forward-addr: 50.116.23.211  # Open

some-other-config:
      key: "value"
```

I am getting the forward zones from variable say FORWARD_ZONES, whose sample value is

```
forward-zone:
      name: "somedns.com"
      forward-addr: 1.1.1.1
      forward-addr: 2.2.2.2

forward-zone:
      name: "someotherdns.com"
      forward-addr: 3.3.3.3
      forward-addr: 4.4.4.4
```

I need to remove all forward zones in the conf file and create new ones as per the input json array received.

So at the end of applying regex i want to have following based on above input

```
## Simple recursive caching DNS, UDP port 53
## unbound.conf -- https://calomel.org
#
server:
   access-control: 10.0.0.0/8 allow
   verbosity: 1

forward-zone:
      name: "somedns.com"
      forward-addr: 1.1.1.1
      forward-addr: 2.2.2.2

forward-zone:
      name: "someotherdns.com"
      forward-addr: 3.3.3.3
      forward-addr: 4.4.4.4

some-other-config:
      key: "value"
```

What regex should i use use over the sed to achieve the above

```
sed -i "whatShouldBeRegexStringHereThatUses_FORWARD_ZONES_variable" unbound.conf
```

EDIT:
This is the playground which also shows what have i done
https://regex101.com/r/x0H2p3/1/

Comment: are all forward-zone sections next to each other in input file? sed/regex not very suitable for this task.. awk with paragraph mode would be better... also, you'll have to add what effort you've made to solve this..

Comment: yes all forward-zone sections next to each other. can you please put the awk solution as answer. It would certainly be helpful.

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/tags/sed/info, it has a Q&A linked that shows how to use shell variables... add the code you've tried to question.. and regex101 is not suitable to test sed regex... it is quite different compared to programming languages

Comment: I've voted to close this question because it appears to be a request for a recommendation for a tool or solution, rather than a request for assistance with your own code. This makes your question off-topic for StackOverflow. If that assessment was incorrect, and you do indeed want help writing your own code, then please [add your work so far to your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/49251367/edit) and I'll happily retract my close vote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following worked for me

```
sed -zri 's/(forward-zone:\s*\n\s*name: \".*\"\s*\n\s*(forward-addr: [0-9\.]*.*\s*\n\s*)+\s*\n\s*)+/$FORWARD_ZONES/' unbound.conf
```

All i needed to get a valid regex
https://regex101.com/r/x0H2p3/2

Then use sed with

```
'-z'
'--null-data'
'--zero-terminated'
     Treat the input as a set of lines, each terminated by a zero byte
     (the ASCII 'NUL' character) instead of a newline.  This option can
     be used with commands like 'sort -z' and 'find -print0' to process
     arbitrary file names.
```

and

```
'-E'
'-r'
'--regexp-extended'
     Use extended regular expressions rather than basic regular
     expressions.  Extended regexps are those that 'egrep' accepts; they
     can be clearer because they usually have fewer backslashes.
     Historically this was a GNU extension, but the '-E' extension has
     since been added to the POSIX standard
     (http://austingroupbugs.net/view.php?id=528), so use '-E' for
     portability.  GNU sed has accepted '-E' as an undocumented option
     for years, and *BSD seds have accepted '-E' for years as well, but
     scripts that use '-E' might not port to other older systems.  *Note
     Extended regular expressions: ERE syntax.
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this can be achieved with `awk` in the following way :

```
awk 'BEGIN{p=1}
     /^[-a-zA-Z]*:[[:blank:]]*$/{p=1}
     /^forward-zone:[[:blank:]]*$/{p=0}
     (p==0&&v==0){print var;print ""; v=1}
     p' var=$FORWARD_ZONES foo.conf
```

It essentially checks with variable `p` if a line needs to be printed or not. If it finds a new configuration block with the regex `^[-a-zA-Z]*:[[:blank:]]*$` then it will defaultly set the printflag `p=1`, however if the configuration block is `^forward-zone:[[:blank:]]*$` it will disable the printing. The first time it disabled the printing, it will inject `$FORWARD_ZONES`.

If you have your forward zones in another file called `forward_zones.conf` then you could use

```
awk 'BEGIN{p=1}
     /^[-a-zA-Z]*:[[:blank:]]*$/{p=1}
     /^forward-zone:[[:blank:]]*$/{while(getline line<f2){print line); p=0}
     (p==0&&v==0){print ""; v=1}
     p' f2=forward_zones.conf foo.conf
```

Answer (score 0):

In GNU sed: `sed -e "/forward-zone/,/^\s*$/d;/some-other/i $FORWARD_ZONES" input-file`

This is a relatively simple deletion of the existing forward-zone sections using `/START/,/END/d` and `/some-other/i` to insert the content of `$FORWARD_ZONES`

Example output:

```
$ export FORWARD_ZONES="newjunk\nnewjunk\n"

$ sed -e "/forward-zone/,/^\s*$/d;/some-other/i $FORWARD_ZONES" fz.txt

server:
   access-control: 10.0.0.0/8 allow
   verbosity: 1

newjunk
newjunk

some-other-config:
      key: "value"
```

If you prefer to insert the contents of another file, with GNU sed, you could insert `new.txt` with:

`sed -e "/forward-zone/,/^\s*$/d;/some-other/e cat new.txt" fz.txt`

Using the GNU sed `e` command to shell out to `cat new.txt` which is immediately appended to the output stream.

Non-GNU sed likely requires a linebreak after `i` and doesn't support the `e` command.  The easy workaround for that is to create a command file to use with `sed -f`.

Comment: Well it is certainly helpful, but trust me now one knows what the some-other-config actually is. it could be xyx-config. So a generic solution will be more helpful.

Comment: Do you care about order at all, then?  You could just delete the stuff you want to delete and add the new stuff at the end of the file.  I can make something that will do either... it's just you make things harder and more hackish to do a sort of in-place replacement in sed mostly because it's a `stream` editor.